# Z3 enumsort update

Tags: set, z3

Is it possible to update an enumerated sort by adding (or removing) a symbol to it? What I would like to do is to add a new value to the list of symbols (see below) even after a variable, say "X", is created from that sort.

```
EnumSort eSort = con.mkEnumSort(name,symbols);
SetSort eSetSort = con.mkSetSort(eSort);
```

If I create a new enumerated sort and get a value "v" then I get an error "domain sort and parameter do not match" for the expression v \in X (membership).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to change sorts. 
You could create a single enumeration sort and add various 
range constraints on sets created over the enumeration sort.